# Lock free equivelant to Boost::condition_variable

Tags: multithreading, boost, synchronization, mutex

Consider the following code

```
bool flag = false;
boost::condition_variable conditional;
boost::mutex mtx;

void wait() {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mtx);
    if (flag)
        return;
    else
        conditional.wait(lock);
}

void produce() {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mtx);
    flag = true;
    conditional.notify_all();
}
```

Let's say there are an arbitrary number of consumers who are asleep in `wait()`. When the producer calls `signal()` they will all wake up and then sequentially obtain and release the lock. Is there a way to sleep each waiter so that when they are woken up by the producer they don't have to go through the unecessary exercise of reobtaining their  lock?

Comment: "produce" usually goes with "consume".  What problem is this supposed to solve?

Comment: You seem to be implementing a "manual reset binary semaphore": a device which blocks any number of threads in its reset state, and then wakes up all waking threads and passes through all newly arriving ones when flipped to its set state.

Comment: @Kaz Threads which are spawned in an objects constructor need to wait for the constructor to return before continueing. So the "producer" generates his work all or nothing.

Comment: @Kaz That description sounds perfect. I will research...

Comment: Which constructor must return? Before you unleash threads on a C++ object, generally speaking, the entire chain of hierarchical constructor calls should return: the object should be in service. You can flout this rule if you know that the threads are only going to touch the already constructed part of the object (the base class part whose constructor has finished already).  And you're sure nothing bad will happen like the remaining constructor activity throwing an exception.

Comment: Practically speaking, the safest thing is to do two steps if you have active objects. completely construct the object, and then call some `.start()` function to activate it, which can just create all the threads. Similarly havea  `stop()` and `join()` to make sure no threads are running prior to destroying the thing.

Comment: @Kaz The constructors of the threads which are spawned must return before the main object (the parent of the threads) can return.